# Can I resize this partition?

Tags: partitioning

My Ubuntu /boot partition is 243M which is just enough to hold one kernel and still be able to upgrade. The partition sits on a 120 GB disk which has this partition table:

```
Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 234440703 233938946 111,6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 234440703 233938944 111,6G 8e Linux LVM
```

My fstab:

```
#                
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d45cc5b0-132b-4151-9663-72041c89535d /boot ext2 defaults   0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw        0       0
/dev/sdb1       /home           ext4    defaults                0       2
```

also

```
$ lsblk /dev/sda
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5                  8:5    0 111,6G  0 part
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0 107,8G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0   3,8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

So the sda5 partition is my / directory. It is currently at 25 GB of 114. Is it safe (or wise) to shrink that partion so I can enlarge sda1?

Comment: If it is safe is a question of proper backups, if it is wise is likely a question of opinion. I'd probably opt for a fresh install with better partitioning. Any reason to use lvm? If not necessary, maybe better to stay with normal partitions. Is the disk gpt or old mbr style partition table? This are things to consider. As your question is worded just right now, your asking for opinions which is discouraged on AskUbuntu.

Comment: There is no particular reason to use lvm. I don't even know what other options there are, I am just using it as it is installed. I installed this server long ago and has been upgraded through the Unbutu versions until 20.04 now. It probably started with 16.04 or even 14.04.
The disk is MBR.